# What is the derivative of $Tr(X^{-\frac{1}{2}}D)$ with respect to $X$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives

In the question, $X$ and $D$ are symmetric positive definite (SPD) matrices, and $Tr(\cdot)$ is the trace of the matrix. $X^{-\frac{1}{2}}X^{-\frac{1}{2}}=X^{-1}$, and $X^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ is also a symmetric positive definite (SPD) matrix.

Just for an example, the derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial X}Tr(X^{-1}D)=-X^{-1}DX^{-1}$, where $X$ and $D$ are symmetric positive definite (SPD) matrices.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

Define the matrix $E_{jk}=e_je_k^T\,$ which has all elements equal to zero, except for the element at the $jk$ position, which equal to one.

Then use Higham's "Complex Step Approximation" to calculate each component of the gradient numerically 
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial X_{jk}} = {\rm Im}\Bigg(\frac{f(X+ihE_{jk})}{h}\Bigg)$$
where $h=10^{-100}$ and $f(X)={\rm tr}\big(X^{-1/2}D\big)$.